# UIWebView intermittently denied access to html5 database storage

Tags: iphone, ios, html, uiwebview, local-storage

I have an iphone app that enables users to login via a native `UIView` on ios, that then fires up a `UIWebView` to display the main content. The webapp uses database storage to retain some of the content locally.

However, every now and then, the webapp will fail to load when attempting to access the database with the following message appearing in the logs.

> ..... sandboxd[3203] : APPNAME(3201) deny file-write-create /Databases.db

I am unable to reproduce the error with any consistency (at first I thought it would only happen in low-memory situations, but further tests have proved that it happens at other times also). The app is set up to retry with a new `UIWebView` if a failure like this happens, but I am noticing once it happens once, it will happen until the app is force-closed. Typically, once closed and re-opened, the app will work as usual.

Memory footprint is quite low, and I have monitored for leaks not finding anything.

Comment: I would suspect that somehow you're getting more than one request going.  Do you do any multi-threading in the app?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with the error: sandboxd[1985] <Notice>: deny file-write-create /private/var/mobile/Applications/<our app id>

Comment: Andrew C, I'm suffering from the same error, did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: fractious, although I never resolved the initial issue (worked around it), what Hot Licks mentioned is probably the most correct answer. Watch out for multi-threading, when writing to the db.

Comment: Same issue here, I can't believe that this has anything to do with multi-threading otherwise it wouldn't keep failing until the app is closed/reopened.

Comment: @Eoin a code sample of you storing storage and trying to retrieve helps people trying to help you.

Comment: also, javascript is quite quirky in uI webview. if you have a native app, i would just use phonegap for the uiwebview part, it works superbly. in phonegaps docs, they teach you how to use it as part of your native app.

Comment: The database limits for WebSQL have changed in iOS 7, are you going above 5MB? Not sure if this could be related, but this has changed and become an issue for many.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you're exceeding the 5MB quota for storing data?

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/?redirect_from_locale=de